# How do I set my application version for Windows in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

When my application crashes, the Windows Event Viewer always reports my application version as "0.0.0.0".
[image: Windows Event Viewer version]
I can't figure how to set the application version in a way that the Windows Event Viewer recognizes. Changing it with [QApplication::setApplicationVersion()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#applicationVersion-prop) doesn't seem to do it.

Obviously there are better ways to debug a program than the Windows Crash Log, but in lieu of all of that, how would I go about setting this value so that Windows recognizes it? My IDE is Qt Creator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the [VERSION](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#version) qmake variable in your `pro` file:

`VERSION = 1.0.0.0`

> On Windows, triggers auto-generation of an .rc file if the RC_FILE and
>   RES_FILE variables are not set. The generated .rc file will have the
>   FILEVERSION and PRODUCTVERSION entries filled with major, minor, patch
>   level, and build number.

Comment: This is exactly right. However, it doesn't work when setting the app icon [as instructed here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/appicon.html) because that'll override the rc file created by `VERSION`. Is there a way to combine these two RC files? `RC_FILE +=` doesn't appear to have the desired effect.

Comment: @Phlucious In Qt 5 there is a handy [`RC_ICONS`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#rc-icons) `qmake` variable, however I'm not sure if it is available in Qt 4. If not, you can always manually combine the contents of both RC files and into a single one and refer to it using `RC_FILE`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! The need to migrate to Qt5 is becoming more and more apparent, even with a QWidget application.

Comment: For me, usage of the RC_FILE variable because VERSION does *not* override the RC_FILE but instead RC_FILE just causes VERSION to not work. I can confirm that using RC_ICONS instead of RC_FILE fixed everything for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you develop a widget app or qml, maybe you want to show your version in `WindowTitle`.

A full solution would be:

In `.pro` file add:

```
VERSION = 1.2.3
DEFINES += APP_VERSION=\\\"$$VERSION\\\"
```

and in `QWidget` or `QMainWindow`:

```
setWindowTitle("Qt " +qtVersion + " Version"+ APP_VERSION);
```

or in `QML`:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    title: "Qt " +qtVersion + " Version"+ APP_VERSION
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `QCoreApplication` class.

```
QCoreApplication::setApplicationVersion("1.0");
```