# Qt application misses start menu and taskbar icon on Windows 10

Tags: c++, qt, icons, windows-10

I'm having issue with the icons of my Qt Windows application on Windows.

I've set the `RC_FILE` with `IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE` and the icon shows correctly in Windows Explorer.

But I'm still missing the taskbar icon and the Icon that should show up in the start menu.

I already replaced the old 32x32 .ico file that worked for Windoes 7 with one having 256x256, 32x32, 48x48 and 16x16 but this didn't help either.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

**Added screenshot for clarity:**

[image]

Comment: We've added an .ico file and an .rc source to our VS project to set our application icon (similar as described in your question). Our GUI is Qt based as well. If I start our application in VS2013 (for debugging) I see a default app icon in the task bar (what confused me a bit until I got used to it). However, in the release built everything is fine. Is this different on your side?

Comment: I remember that I once (on Windows 7 or even XP) changed/fixed an app icon after having the application already built and tested. I noticed that the update in Explorers thumbnail view was quite delayed. I assumed that Windows/Explorer had somewhere cached the old icon and a certain time later this annoying effect vanished. (Hence, I didn't dig deeper...)

Comment: @Scheff: we don't use VS, we crosscompile from Linux using mingw64. I already feared that VS might use some poorly documented 'magic' to make icons work. And as I mentioned, Explorer is fine, it's what goes into the taskbar when the application runs.

Comment: It's years ago that I once made an .rc file manually probably reading a doc from anywhere. Since then, I've made them by copy/paste as it was working. Therefore, I cannot tell why these things are there. However, my `.rc` files contain two icon entries: `IDI_ICON1                 ICON    DISCARDABLE     "myApp.ico"` and `IDI_APPICON               ICON                    "myApp.ico"`. I just googled `IDI_APPICON` but all I could find were a `#define IDI_APPICON 101` in some hits. I even don't know where the `IDI`s come from on my side. WinAPI? There is no such definition in our sources.

Comment: Btw. there is also a comment in my `.rc` file that the order of icon definitions is important:
`// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.`

Comment: Regarding Explorer and taskbar - that's the same (somehow): [How to Restart Windows’ Explorer.exe (Along with the Taskbar and Start Menu)](https://www.howtogeek.com/198815/use-this-secret-trick-to-close-and-restart-explorer.exe-in-windows/).

Comment: So, just adding the IDI_APPICON entry to the doesn't seem to change anything...

Comment: Well, yes, the whole desktop and therefore the taskbar are part of explorer.exe. But it still seems that Explorer's File Browser and the taskbar take the icons from different sources.

Comment: I was able to prompt Explorer to change the pinned Start icon by right-clicking, then “Resize,” and then going from medium to small and then back again.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mark which Qt version you're using, so I'll comment on both qt4 and qt5.

**Taskbar Icon**

In both versions the Windows taskbar icon is derived from your Dialog/MainWindow/Widget's icon (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29285256). You can set this for the specific window and its children with [QWidget::setWindowIcon()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowIcon-prop).

This should solve your problem, but I'll talk about the Explorer icon, too, for the sake of completeness.

**Explorer/Start Menu Icon**

Explorer.exe and the Start Menu icons are derived from a *.rc file generated either by you or by qmake. You can set this using your own *.rc file with [RC_FILE in Qt4 or Qt5](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#rc-file) as described in the comments to your question and I believe you've attempted, but [sometimes this will create a conflict with other qmake calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43262011) like `VERSION` that create a second *.rc file that overrides the first.

Unfortunately, in Qt4 you're out of luck. You must either do all of that work yourself in the *.rc file or give up some features like VERSION.

However, Qt5 added a new option [RC_ICON](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#rc-icons) that plays nicely with the other RC-related qmake variables. As long as you're okay with qmake generating the *.rc file, that should do the trick.

The application icon set here *should* cascade to the window icon in the taskbar and title bar, but in my experience it doesn't seem to happen and it makes more sense to set them separately. The resolutions are different anyway so it's nice to have finer control.

See this link for official Qt5 documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html